# Concatenate atttributes SQL

Tags: sql, concatenation

I’ve got this code that was wrote in SQL Server!
I want to concatenate U.Prefixo with U.ShortID, is that possible?

```
Create view Reserva_Utilizador
as
Select DISTINCT E.Descricao, R.IDReserva, t.descricao as Estados , U.Prefixo,          U.ShortID, U.Nome
from Equipamento E, ReservaEquipamento RE, tipoEstadoReserva t, Utilizador U, Reserva   R, EstadoReserva ER
where ER.IDReserva = R.IDReserva
and R.Prefixo = U.Prefixo
and R.ShortID = U.ShortID
and R.IDReserva = RE.IDReserva
and RE.IDequipamento = E.codEquipamento
and t.codEstado = ER.IDestado 
Go
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible: `U.Prefixo + ' ' + U.ShortID`

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate in SQL Server, you can just use `+`. For non string data types, case them to `varchar` or `nvarchar`:

```
Select U.Prefixo + cast(U.ShortID as varchar(10)),
```

Answer (score 0):

U.Prefixo + '_' + U.ShortID as username, p.ex

Do this and it works!!

PS: send a hug to your cousin ;)